# cmake: dependencies on object libraries

Tags: cmake

Assume the following directory strcuture:

```
CMakeLists.txt
libA
    contents: a.cpp 
              a.h
src
    contents: hello.cpp
              target1.cpp
              target2.cpp
include
    - contents: hello.h
```

I have a static library **A**, used within the main source code of the project.

**Attempt 1**:

```
. . .
add_executable(t1 src/target1.cpp src/hello.cpp)
add_dependancies(libA)
target_include_directories(t1 PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
target_link_libraries(t1 PRIVATE /path/to/libA)
. . .
```

This works for `t1`, however, if I want to compile `target2.cpp` I would need to repeat this process, hence `hello.o` is generated twice.

**Attempt 2**:
I was thinking to change this approach to generate an object library for `hello.cpp`, and simply add the object library to the targets. Yet, I get compilation problems as it cannot find the headers defined in library *A* as the object library is compiled first and the heade files are not yet copied to the `CMakeFiles`.

```
. . .
add_library(libA src/hello.cpp)
add_executable(t1 src/target1.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libA>)
add_dependancies(libA)
target_include_directories(t1 PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
target_link_libraries(t1 PRIVATE /path/to/libA)
. . .
```

Is there a way to define a dependancy, so that the static library **A** is compiled before?

Comment: How does compilation order affect whether headers are found or not? What is the relationship between the object files and the static library? I'm afraid your question is rather unclear. Can you add a (suitably minimised, but still demonstrative) example of your CMake code?

Comment: @Angew thank you for your comments. I have updated the question. Hope now it is more clear. I am pretty new to cmake so I might have gotten some basic concept horribly wrong.

Comment: "and the heade files are not yet copied to the `CMakeFiles`" - where, how, and why are you copying the header files?

Comment: I said this, as the libA is actually an external   project which is included in the main project via ExternalProject_Add. Hence all the files from the library are copied to the CMakeFiles directory.

Comment: That's pretty important info that should have been in the question right from the start! You should [edit] it in.

Comment: just in case `add_library(Foo OBJECT ...)` is an "object" library and it's a very bad idea to use it since you can't use `target_link_libraries` on it, so if it depend on Bar you'll need pass: `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Bar,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>`, `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Bar,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>`, `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Bar,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>` by hand using `target_include_directories`, `target_compile_options`, and `target_compile_definitions` respectively

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you've mentioned that `libA` is actually brought into the buildsystem using `ExternalProject_Add`. Which means that you're mixing "normal" and external projects in the same `CMakeLists.txt`, and that's highly discouraged.

The preferred way of working with ExternalProject is the so-called Superbuild approach: treat *all* the projects as external and add them with `ExternalProject_Add`, including your own project. That way, the master CMakeList becomes just the superbuild — a container and driver for subprojects. At this level, you can introduce dependencies between the individual projects as necessary.

Configure and build the superbuild once to get all projects set up correctly. After that, go one level lower and work on your project as if it was standalone; all dependencies will have been already prepared and ready.