# How do you make CMake skip an ExternalProject on subsequent runs?

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake for a project where I want to bundle Clang. I use ExternalProject_Add to build clang from source. However, since Clang and LLVM is huge, a `make` with nothing changed takes 45 seconds.

Is there a way to make CMake just build the ExternalProject once, and then not even check if anything has changed on subsequent runs if it has already been built successfully?

Comment: Are you using the recommended [superbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308072/1782465) approach, where your real project is just another `ExternalProject_Add`?

Comment: No, I didn't know that was recommended. I don't understand why that's not mentioned in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html), but it sounds like a good idea, and is indeed recommended [on their blog](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/).

Comment: @Angew So, I've made a superbuild which adds Clang as an ExternalProject, and adds my own project as an ExternalProject which depends on Clang. Even when I run `make myproject`, CMake will check if Clang is up to date, which takes just as much time as it did before.

Comment: Are you running `make myproject` in the top-level build directory (wrong), or in the build directory of the "external" subproject (correct)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use `ExternalProject_Add()` is to structure your project as a [superbuild](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/). This means that your top-level project (the "superbuild") does not build any actual code and instead consists only of `ExternalProject_Add` calls. Your "real" project is added as one of these "external" projects. This allows you to set up the superbuild with all dependencies, ordering, etc.

The workflow is then as follows:

1. Generate the superbuild project.
2. Build the superbuild project. This will build and install all dependencies, and also generate (and build) your real project.
3. Switch to the buildsystem generated for your real project and start doing further development using that. Your dependencies are already correctly set up and installed by the build of the superbuild project in the previous step, and will never be checked for out-of-dateness by the build.
4. If you ever need to change the setup of your dependencies, do it and build the superbuild again.